# Instantiate Class at Specific Time

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to make a simple game using libgdx. One thing that I am stuck with is making enemies spawn at specific times. If I do something like

```
if (t == 10) 
    new Enemy();
```

I might miss this specific time or maybe spawn the same enemy twice. What I have right now is something like

```
float t = 0
float timeElapsed = 0;

update (float delta) {
    timeElapsed += getDeltaTime();
    if (timeElapsed > 0.1) {
        t++;
        timeElapsed = 0;
    }
}
```

This gives me the approximate elapsed time in tenths of seconds for t, but it really doesn't feel like the way I should be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution I use in my games that might be useful. I actually created a Timer class:

```
public class Timer
{
    protected float remaining;
    protected float interval;

    public Timer(float interval)
    {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.remaining = interval;
    }

    public boolean hasTimeElapsed() { return (remaining < 0.0F); }

    public void reset() { remaining = interval; }

    public void reset(float interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.remaining = interval;
    }

    public void update(float delta) { remaining -= delta; }
}
```

You initialize the Timer to a certain time period, then in your update(delta) method you call Timer.update(delta) on all your Timers, then check if any of the timers have elapsed by calling Timer.hasTimeElapsed().

In your case, you only need one Timer object, since the enemies are spawned in sequence. Once you spawn an enemy, you reset the Timer (changing the spawn period if you want) and wait for it to go off again.

You can also modify the Timer object to use the subject-observer pattern in order to trigger callbacks when a timer goes off. This is useful if you have logic that needs to know when a timed event occurs, but the logic does not have direct access to the delta time.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have a slow frame with eg. getDeltaTime() = 0.2, the enemy's spawn will be delayed.

The simplest way that comes to mind is to get rid of t - compare directly against timeElapsed, and keep track of the object references to know whether you've spawned each enemy. ie.

```
if (enemy1 == NULL && elapsedTime > 10) {
    enemy1 = new Enemy();
}
if (enemy2 == NULL && elapsedTime > 30) {
    enemy2 = new Enemy();
}
```

For a more scalable approach, you could create a linked list of spawn times, and when you spawn an enemy advance the list pointer. That way you only have to compare against one time (the spawn-time on the current list node) per frame.

Addendum: it's rarely a good idea to use == in the context of floating point numbers. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html for gory details.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this solution before. I think that the linked list you talked about would be a better approach though, because I am going to be using a lot of objects. I am thinking that I'll have a linked that has a time that is decremented until it reaches zero and then move on to the next element in the list. Each element would also have a list of Enemies spawned at the same time and would be blank if I need a delay.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach - you could also keep it to a single list by having multiple enemies in a row with time==0.

Also note you might have to change your instantiation semantics (eg, by adding a .spawn() method to the Enemy class rather than spawning in the constructor), since if you want to keep a list of enemies, you'll need to instantiate enemies at list creation time (or use some factory-type pattern).

Comment: I actually ended up using a single linked list where each node is an enemy and a delay. The enemies are instantiated and added to the linked list, but do not become active until they are reached. They are then stored in an array of active enemies. Here it is on [github](https://github.com/russjohnson09/bullethell) for anyone who might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you increment `t` and then you spawn enemies based on `t` value. Why don't you do it like this ?

```
final float step = 0.1f;
float timeElapsed = 0f;

update (float delta) {
    timeElapsed += delta;
    while (timeElapsed > step){
         timeElapsed-=step;
         createEnemy();
    }
}
```

With this approach, when your game lags and you get delta lets say 0.5f and you step is 0.1, you will create 5 enemies. I don't know if you want or don't want this beviour